# transfering variables between main page to internal pages

Tags: php, jquery, html

In a way to separate the html and php code, I came up to the following structure -
Index.php - The brain of the code - receive data, process data and then choose what page to sent to the user.

Before accessing the main site, you have to login or register. After you do that ,index.php will load the site.html which will have the dyn_content block - The content will be loaded by javascript depending on what link clicked by the user.

index.php

```
...
case "inside": {
            site();
            break;
        }
...
function site () {
    $Page = file_get_contents("site.html");
    echo $Page;  // if it is not good way to display page, plz let me know the better way.
    return 1;   
}
...
```

site.html

```
...
<div id="main_page">

            <div id="dyn_content">

            </div>
        </div>
...
```

jquery

```
...
$(document).on("click",'#link_profile',  function (){   
        $("#dyn_content").load("in_page/profile.php",function() {
            $('#m_main_top').load("menu/m_profile.php");});
            return false;
    });
$(document).on("click",'#link_setings',  function (){   
        $("#dyn_content").load("in_page/set.php",function() {
            $('#m_main_top').load("menu/m_set.php");});
            return false;
    });
...
```

To display the data when page is loaded in din_content, I need get it from database (user data for profile.php for an example). Since I separated the code, I need to do it in index.php (I can't do it in profile.php since it will destroy the concept of separation). However the variables in index.php is not visible in pages loaded in dyn_content  (but I  expect that they will work since we still in index.php).

So the first question - is it posible to make the index variables visible in pages loaded in block dyn_content? May be the problem is that the page site.html is already loaded by index.php, and when the pages (pages in dyn_content block) loaded by jquery is too late since this action happen on user side?

So I come up with idea - to get all requrement data in some sort of space, and then take this data when it needed. So I come up with the following ideas how to do it:

1. I thought about to transfer variables from index.php to jquery and then from jquery to the dyn_block page. But I think it is not the best way.
2. Sent the json data from index.php to other pages. It is look good, but the problem is that we don't know the destination until user will click on one of the links (it can be settings.php or profile.php or other links). Plus the data must be processed only when the page need to be displayed. So I have problem with realization that idea and I'm not sure that it is the best one.
3. Use Sessions or browser's cach. It is, I think, the best way how to do it. But I'm not sure if it good since we can use 50 variables that will take user place. And if it is already full on user side, we will have problem with displaying data.

So it is all ideas what I get.
So the question is - Can I make the variables in index.php make visible in internal parts as was described above? if no, how better to transfer them?

Answer (score 0):

There is more unified and simplified approach:
Let's say you have initial html parts right inside your index.php:

```
// index.php content
...
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=profile">Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=settings">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.php?page=other">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
...

...
<div id="main_page">
    <div id="dyn_content">

    if(isset($_GET['page']) && !empty($_GET['page'])){
       switch($_GET['page']){
           case "profile":
               $some_variable = 111;
               $profile_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; // just for example
               include ("in_page/profile.php");
               break;
           case "settings":
               $some_variable = 222;
               include ("in_page/set.php");
               break;
           default:
               include ("index.php");

       }
    }

    </div>
</div>

...
```

From inside any included page, you may access global variables of "parent" page declared before inclusion

```
// profile.php content
<a href="/users/<?php echo $profile_id ?>">My link</a></br>
<img src="/users/images/<?php echo $profile_id ?>"/> // avatar
... // approximate content
```

Comment: Sorry, but in the beginning I told that I trying separate HTML and php, in your example you combine it. index.php -do only php work, no html tags at all, index.php combine and load the page what user need